# removing key value pairs by matching values python

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I am searching for periods "." in a dictionary and trying to delete the key/value pair if I find it

```
if "." in dict.values():
    #delete key, value pair from the dictionary
```

I am sure this is very simple but I cannot seem to locate an explanation. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: `{key:value for key, value in dict_obj.items() if '.' not in value}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a new dictionary without those unwanted values using dictionary comprehension. Here is an example of how to do it:

```
>>> old_dict = {'one': '.', 'two': 2, 'three':3, 'four':'.'}
>>> new_dict = {k:v for k,v in old_dict.iteritems() if not v == '.'}
>>> new_dict
 {'three': 3, 'two': 2}
```

using `iteritems` instead of `items` avoids creating an intermediate list and improves performance.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to copy your dictionary, (for example if the dictionary is large, or you have a reference to it elsewhere) then you should do it this way:

```
ks = [k for k in d if d[k]=='.']
for k in ks:
    d.pop(k)
```

Create your list of keys to be removed ahead of time as shown above.  You don't want to modify your dictionary while iterating over it.